# How to compare files with different columns in unix?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, grep

I want to compare filenames of Today.txt with Main.txt.
If there is match, then print all 6 columns of matched file of Main.txt with a new file say matched.txt.

and the files which are not matched with Main.txt, then list the filename and time of TODAY.txt in a new file say unmatched.txt

Main.txt

```
 date      filename          timestamp space  count   status
Nov 4    +CHCK01_20161104.txt  06:39   2.15M  17153    on_time
Nov 4    TRIPS11_20161104.txt 09:03   0.00M  24       On_Time
Nov 4    AR02_20161104.txt    09:31   0.00M  7        On_Time
Nov 4    AR01_20161104.txt    09:31   0.04M  433      On_Time
```

Today.txt

```
 filename       time
CHCK01_20161104.txt 06:03
CHCK05_20161104.txt 11:10
CHCK09_20161104.txt 21:46
AR01_20161104.txt   09:36
AR02_20161104.txt   09:36
ifs01_20161104.txt  21:16
TRIPS11_20161104.txt 09:16
```

Required Output:
matched.txt

```
Nov 4    +CHCK01_20161104.txt  06:39   2.15M  17153    on_time
Nov 4    TRIPS11_20161104.txt 09:03   0.00M  24       On_Time
Nov 4    AR02_20161104.txt    09:31   0.00M  7        On_Time
Nov 4    AR01_20161104.txt    09:31   0.04M  433      On_Time
```

unmatched.txt

```
CHCK05_20161104.txt 11:10
CHCK09_20161104.txt 21:46
ifs01_20161104.txt  21:16
```

Could you please help me on this please ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{next} 
      NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} 
      $3 in a{print; delete a[$3]} 
          END{for(k in a) print k,a[k] > "unmatched"}' today main > matched

$ head *matched

==> matched <==
Nov 4    CHCK01_20161104.txt  06:39   2.15M  17153    on_time
Nov 4    TRIPS11_20161104.txt 09:03   0.00M  24       On_Time
Nov 4    AR02_20161104.txt    09:31   0.00M  7        On_Time
Nov 4    AR01_20161104.txt    09:31   0.04M  433      On_Time

==> unmatched <==
ifs01_20161104.txt 21:16
CHCK09_20161104.txt 21:46
CHCK05_20161104.txt 11:10
```

Comment: For tab delimited output you can set `-v OFS='\t'`

Comment: I got a question for you. I am printing the files which are in inprogress directory with plus(+) symbol like example.
Nov 4    +CHCK01_20161104.txt  06:39   2.15M  17153    on_time
The files which are in inprogress they will appended with plus(+) symbol and other files will be in same name in main.txt
I want the files with + symbol and other files in my required output(matched), Please suggest how do I compare main.txt and Today.txt to get matched and unmatched.txt ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`, one each for `matched` and `unmatched`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $3 in a{print > "matched.txt"}' Today.txt Main.txt 
$ cat matched.txt 
Nov 4    CHCK01_20161104.txt  06:39   2.15M  17153    on_time
Nov 4    TRIPS11_20161104.txt 09:03   0.00M  24       On_Time
Nov 4    AR02_20161104.txt    09:31   0.00M  7        On_Time
Nov 4    AR01_20161104.txt    09:31   0.04M  433      On_Time

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$3]; next} !($1 in a) && FNR>1{print > "unmatched.txt"}' Main.txt Today.txt 
$ cat unmatched.txt 
CHCK05_20161104.txt 11:10
CHCK09_20161104.txt 21:46
ifs01_20161104.txt  21:16
```

- Logic is similar, initialize array `a` with required column of first file argument to `awk`
- Then based on whether filename from second file should be present or not in `a`, print to required output file

With `grep` and `awk` combination:

```
$ grep -Ff <(awk 'NR>1{print $1}' Today.txt) Main.txt 
Nov 4    CHCK01_20161104.txt  06:39   2.15M  17153    on_time
Nov 4    TRIPS11_20161104.txt 09:03   0.00M  24       On_Time
Nov 4    AR02_20161104.txt    09:31   0.00M  7        On_Time
Nov 4    AR01_20161104.txt    09:31   0.04M  433      On_Time

$ grep -vFf <(awk 'NR>1{print $3}' Main.txt) Today.txt | tail -n+2
CHCK05_20161104.txt 11:10
CHCK09_20161104.txt 21:46
ifs01_20161104.txt  21:16
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer using pipe power.

```
tail -n +2 /tmp/today | while read a b; do \
    if ! grep $a /tmp/main >> /tmp/matched; then \
        echo $a $b; \
    fi; \
done > /tmp/unmatched
```

Explanation

Print /tmp/today except for the first line

```
tail -n +2 /tmp/today
```

Read the file in two variables

```
while read a b
```

grep the $a in /tmp/main and store in a file

```
grep $a /tmp/main >> /tmp/matched
```

If the grep returned non-zero then echo $a and $b

```
echo $a $b
```

Output:

```
root@do:~# cat /tmp/matched
Nov 4    CHCK01_20161104.txt  06:39   2.15M  17153    on_time
Nov 4    AR01_20161104.txt    09:31   0.04M  433      On_Time
Nov 4    AR02_20161104.txt    09:31   0.00M  7        On_Time
Nov 4    TRIPS11_20161104.txt 09:03   0.00M  24       On_Time
root@do:~# cat /tmp/unmatched
CHCK05_20161104.txt 11:10
CHCK09_20161104.txt 21:46
ifs01_20161104.txt 21:16
root@do:~#
```